# What is the best way to populate a boost::multi_array from an initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-multi-array

I'd like to initialize a boost::multi_array inline in some code. But I don't think the boost::multi_array supports initialization from an initializer list. Here's what I have so far:

```
// First create a primitive array, which can be directly initialized
uint8_t field_primitive[4][8] = {
    { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
    { 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2 },
    { 1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2 },
    { 1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 }
};
// Create the boost::multi_array I actually want to use
boost::multi_array<uint8_t, 2> field(boost::extents[4][8]);
// Compact but yucky approach to copying the primitive array contents into the multi_array.
memcpy(field.data(), field_primitive, field.num_elements() * sizeof(uint8_t));
```

I like that I can compactly express the matrix contents using the curly brace intializer list. But I don't like the "memcpy" and I don't like the use of a throwaway primitive array. Is there a nicer way to populate my boost::multi_array from a readable inline set of values in the code?

Comment: Perhaps something here helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824247/one-line-initialiser-for-boost-multiarray

Comment: The following link from thecppboostlibraries shows an example using `origin()` and `memcpy`: https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.multiarray

Comment: @Tas the question you linked related to creating a multi_array with certain DIMENSIONS. My question is about creating a multi_array with certain CONTENTS.

Comment: @StephanLechner Thanks for that link. The fact that the official boost documentation contains an example using `memcpy` implies that my solution might be the best. I'm not sure about `origin()` vs. `data()`.

Comment: Are you opposed to writing your own function (aka: `create_multi_array<uint8_t, 2>(extents[4][8], { { 1, 1, ... }, ... })`)? Unfortunately, Boost.MultiArray hasn't been updated with `initializer_list` support.

Comment: Still trying to find out if `data()` or `origin()` shall be used.

Comment: After further study it appears that origin() is more appropriated than data(), though they are usually the same value.

Comment: Hm - did also some studies which let me tend to use `data()`. I added these thoughts to the answer; maybe you can review these thoughts.

Comment: theboostcpplibraries, however good, is not official Boost documentation. The example there uses memcpy because it assigns chars from a quoted c-string; otherwise it is better to use std::copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example from the official boost documentation concerning [multi_array](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.multiarray)uses `memcpy`, too, though in combination with `origin()`. So it seems to be OK using it:

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
  boost::multi_array<char, 2> a{boost::extents[2][6]};

  typedef boost::multi_array<char, 2>::array_view<1>::type array_view;
  typedef boost::multi_array_types::index_range range;
  array_view view = a[boost::indices[0][range{0, 5}]];

  std::memcpy(view.origin(), "tsooB", 6);
  std::reverse(view.begin(), view.end());

  std::cout << view.origin() << '\n';

  boost::multi_array<char, 2>::reference subarray = a[1];
  std::memcpy(subarray.origin(), "C++", 4);

  std::cout << subarray.origin() << '\n';
}
```

Concerning the difference between `origin()` and `data()`, the [multiarray reference manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#idp18737792) defines the following:

> element* data(); This returns a pointer to the beginning of the
>   contiguous block that contains the array's data. If all dimensions of
>   the array are 0-indexed and stored in ascending order, this is
>   equivalent to origin().
>
> element* origin(); This returns the origin element of the multi_array.

So there seem to be two things to consider when using `data()` and `origin()` together with `memcpy`, ff the array contains dimensions that are not 0-indexed or not in ascending order:

First, `origin()` might not point to the start of the continuous memory block used by the array. Hence, copying memory in the size of the multiarray to this location might exceed the reserved memory block.

Second, on the other hand, copying a memory block to `data()`'s address might lead to a memory layout where array indices as accessed through multiarray do not correspond to the indizes of the memory block copied into the array's internal data buffer.

So it seems to me that using `memcpy` to (pre)-fill a multiarray should be used with care and ideally with 0-based indices and ascending order.

Comment: If the array internal order is not ascending, neither data() nor origin() can save you from what memcpy() will do here. You'll need some loops or iterators in that case. Otherwise I prefer origin() because I expect element [0][0] of my primitive temporary to end up at position [0][0] of the multi_array. Suddenly I think maybe I should really use std::copy here rather than memcpy.

Comment: thecppboostlibraries book is not official documentation. It is good in general, but the memcpy example is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no reason to use `memcpy`.
The example code that you saw is using `memcpy` just because it is transforming a c-string into an array of `char`.
`std::copy[_n]` is better here:

```
...
boost::multi_array<uint8_t, 2> field(boost::extents[4][8]);
std::copy_n(&field_primitive[0][0], field.num_elements(), field.data());
```

Second, you can write a helper function that takes a c-array and returns the array you want:

```
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M, class T>
boost::multi_array<T, 2> make_boost_multi_array(T const(&in)[N][M]) {
    boost::multi_array<uint8_t, 2> ret(boost::extents[N][M]);
    std::copy_n(&in[0][0], ret.num_elements(), ret.data());
    return ret;
}
...
boost::multi_array<uint8_t, 2> field = make_boost_multi_array(field_primitive);
```

See that there is less redundancy.

In fact, you don't need the auxiliary c-array anymore:

```
boost::multi_array<uint8_t, 2> field = make_boost_multi_array<4, 8, uint8_t>({
  { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
  { 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2 },
  { 1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2 },
  { 1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 }
});
```

or

```
boost::multi_array<uint8_t, 2> field = make_boost_multi_array(
  (uint8_t[4][8]){
    { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
    { 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2 },
    { 1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2 },
    { 1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 }
  }
);
```

Finally, you can use a similar multidimensional array library (not Boost.MultiArray) that supports initialization list natively (disclaimer, I wrote the library):

```
#include<multi/array.hpp>  // library from https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/
...
multi::array<uint8_t, 2> field = {
    { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
    { 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2 },
    { 1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2 },
    { 1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 }
};
```

which doesn't have redundancy at all.

See all the examples compiling here: https://godbolt.org/z/YEdsTMGKz